# Error (Key Error 0) when trying to calculate gradient for an ML model. I think it has something to with the dimensions but can't find the problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**Computes the gradient for linear regression**

*Args:*

X (ndarray (m,n)): Data, m examples with n features

y (ndarray (m,)) : target values

w (ndarray (n,)) : model parameters
b (scalar)       : model parameter

**Returns:**

dj_dw (ndarray (n,)): The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameters w.

dj_db (scalar):       The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameter b.

```py
import numpy as np
 
def gradient(X, y, w, b): 

    m,n = X.shape           #(number of examples, number of features)
    dj_dw = np.zeros((n,))
    dj_db = 0
    for i in range(m):                             
        err = (np.dot(X[i],w) + b) - y[i] 
        for j in range(n):                         
            dj_dw[j] = dj_dw[j] + err * X[i, j]    
        dj_db = dj_db + err                        
    dj_dw = dj_dw / m                                
    dj_db = dj_db / m                                
        
    return dj_db, dj_dw

b_init = 785.1811367994083
w_init = np.array([ 0.39133535, 18.75376741, -53.36032453, -26.42131618,-33.2342342])
tmp_dj_db, tmp_dj_dw = gradient(X_train, y_train, w_init, b_init)
print(f'dj_db at initial w,b: {tmp_dj_db}')
print(f'dj_dw at initial w,b: \n {tmp_dj_dw}')
```

**This is the exact error I'm getting**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-1f87825d3f02> in <module>
      1 b_init = 785.1811367994083
      2 w_init = np.array([ 0.39133535, 18.75376741, -53.36032453, -26.42131618,-33.2342342])
----> 3 tmp_dj_db, tmp_dj_dw = gradient(X_train, y_train, w_init, b_init)
      4 print(f'dj_db at initial w,b: {tmp_dj_db}')
      5 print(f'dj_dw at initial w,b: \n {tmp_dj_dw}')

<ipython-input-72-52811c00c1ad> in gradient(X, y, w, b)
     16     dj_db = 0
     17     for i in range(m):
---> 18         err = (np.dot(X.iloc[i,],w) + b) - y[i]
     19         for j in range(n):
     20             dj_dw[j] = dj_dw[j] + err * X.iloc[i, j]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1049 
   1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1053 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 1
```

[**This it the dataset - It's a drive link**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_NwpJT-8xGfU_-3llUl2sgPu0xllOrX/view)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

**Dataset**

Comment: I cannot tell exactly without running, and for that, I need data, but I think you need to change `np.zeros((n,))` to `np.zeros((n,1))`

Comment: Also, could you tell on what line exactly the error is occurring

Comment: May be just :  np.zeros(n) , Aldo dud you checked the size of X_train ?

Comment: @Salahuddin The error occurs at **err = (np.dot(X[i],w) + b) - y[I]**

Comment: @PtitXav The shape of X is (3000,5) and the shape of w is (5,) so the dot product should work but I don't what's causing it

Comment: NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined

Comment: I have added the error I am getting

Comment: This line `err = (np.dot(X.iloc[i,],w) + b) - y[i]` is different from the one you have pasted above `err = (np.dot(X[i],w) + b) - y[i] `. Is `X_train` a `pd.DataFrame` or `np.ndarray`

Comment: If possible, could you share dataset, so that I can perform a test run

Comment: @Salahuddin Yea so for accessing elements I had to use iloc rather than the previous notation but the doubt is still the same. Also I used pd.read_csv to import the data into a data frame.

Comment: I have added the link to the dataset

Comment: Ok, I will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected the issue was that you were trying to iterate over pandas dataframe. This should work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def gradient(X, y, w, b):
    m, n = X.shape  # (number of examples, number of features)
    dj_dw = np.zeros((n,))
    dj_db = 0
    for i in range(m):
        err = (np.dot(X[i], w) + b) - y[i]
        for j in range(n):
            dj_dw[j] = dj_dw[j] + err * X[i, j]
        dj_db = dj_db + err
    dj_dw = dj_dw / m
    dj_db = dj_db / m

    return dj_db, dj_dw


b_init = 785.1811367994083
w_init = np.array([0.39133535, 18.75376741, -53.36032453, -26.42131618, -33.2342342])
data = pd.read_csv(r'USA_Housing - USA_Housing.csv')
X_train, y_train = data.drop(['Price'], axis=1, errors='ignore'), data['Price']
tmp_dj_db, tmp_dj_dw = gradient(X_train.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy(), w_init, b_init)
print(f'dj_db at initial w,b: {tmp_dj_db}')
print(f'dj_dw at initial w,b: \n {tmp_dj_dw}')
```